# How should I implement the model interface when one of the identifiers in the response is a number in an Angular app

Tags: angular, interface, response, numeric, angular12

sample response from the api :

```
"results":[
      {
         "id":16228,
         "name":"ABCD",
         "preview":"/d8a/d8a61a3a12e52114afdbc28f2c813f5c.jpg",
         "data":{
            "480":"https://mdb.net/steam/6693661/movie480.mp4",
            "max":"https://mdb.net/steam/6693661/movie_max.mp4"
         }
```

I have the interface as follows:

```
interface Movie {
  data: {
    max: string;
    480: string;
  };
}
```

When I try to

```
<video
        class="movie"
        controls
        *ngFor="let trailer of results"
      >
        <source src="{{ trailer.data.480 }}" <-------- Error here
         type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

> NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token '0.48' at column 14 in [{{ trailer.data.480 }}]

How can this be resolved ?

Also how can I fix {{ trailer.data?['480'] }}, when the question mark is there

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `{{ trailer.data['480'] }}`

Comment: You should remove the dot, and use single quotes, like the answer suggests. `trailer.data['480']`

Comment: And to help you type that, you should do something like `['480']: string` in your `Movie` interface.

Comment: Also how can I fix {{ trailer.data?['480'] }}, when the question mark is there?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if data is undefined. You could also use a ternary operator inside the curly brackets